# Crystal Reports: Database fields are not appearing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a report which is not displaying data. Only one data field in a subreport is appearing. The rest are just blank. I dragged the database fields directly from the Database Fields.

The dataset is being filled properly, and Verify Data says the DB is up to date.

Thoughts, suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems a while ago with Crystal Reports not accepting text fields of arbitrary length. These fields are called memo fields in MS Access, and I don't know how they are called in your database, but maybe the problem relates to text length on your site, too.

I had to create wrapper views that return varchar(8192) instead of the real field length.

Comment: No memo fields are used, mostly Varchar20s